# Cronjob is not working in Custom Module

Tags: module, magento-1, cron, crontab

I have configured cronjob in my server and confirmed its working fine. Also I have configured cronjob in my custom module but its not working.
Here is my custom module coding for cronjob :

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <company_module>
            <class>Company_Module_Model</class>
        </company_module>
    </models>
</global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <company_module>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>module/observer::moduleUpdate</model>
                </run>
            </company_module>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <Company_Module_First>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_Module</module>
                    <frontName>company-module</frontName>
                </args>
            </Company_Module_First>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Observer.php**

```
class Company_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function moduleUpdate()
    {
        Mage::log('Cron Working', null, 'cron.log', true);
    }
}
```

**Note :** Here I have generated cron.log file for every 5 mins to check whether cron is working. But cron.log file is not generating. I have confirmed cron is working in server.

Why cron.log file is not generating?

Any helps are welcome with thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to your config.xml,

```
<model>module/observer::moduleUpdate</model>
```

Should be

```
<model>company_module/observer::moduleUpdate</model>
```

For `cron.log`, check if logging is enable or not from admin.

**System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Log Settings**

**Edit:** ... or add `true` as 4th parameter, to force logging (independent of config settings)